# How to update the rules after you change DSLR file?

Tags: java, drools

I'm writing a program using DROOLS.For writing rules I use DSL. I have a question. After changes DSLR the file (deletion, addition) to update the rules in working memory? After you add the rule the new rule does not appear in working memory.

```
public class Drools {
private KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase;

public Drools() {
    knowledgeBase = createKnowledgeBaseFromDSL();
}

private KnowledgeBase createKnowledgeBaseFromDSL() {
    KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/simple.dsl"), ResourceType.DSL);
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/simple.dslr"), ResourceType.DSLR);

    if (builder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(builder.getErrors().toString());
    }

    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());

    return knowledgeBase;
}

public void fireAllRules() throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (BufferedReader fileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/main/resources/setting.properties"))) {
        properties.load(fileReader);
        StatefulKnowledgeSession session = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        try {
            HttpReader reader = new HttpReader(properties.getProperty("url"));
            session.insert(reader);
            session.fireAllRules();
        } finally {
            session.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Updating DSL or DRL or DSLR files doesn't change the ongoing session automatically.

Drools 5 had a service for monitoring a directory and automatically rebuilding the knowledge base and updating the session. But this has not been continued in Drools 6.

What to do depends on your use case. You can monitor a directory quite easily using Java features. Then, rebuild as with the code you have. Then, I think, the best way is to start a new session. But this depends on how your data arrives and is or is not kept in Working Memory.